# Create two users with access to privilege level 15 on Cisco IOS

Tags: cisco, authentication

I have a Cisco router running IOS 12.4.

What's the simplest way to:

- have two users (e.g. user1 and user2), each with his own password
- both of which can log in via telnet remotely
- both of which have access to enable to reach privilege level 15, **with their passsword**

I've tried many things already, like "user user1 privilege 15 secret xyz", but they must resort to use the system-wide "enable secret" password anyway.

"aaa new-model" is enabled.

Comment: have you contacted Cisco?  They would be able to best answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following will do pretty close to what you want; they will dump in to priv 15 upon login automatically.

```
aaa authorization exec default local
```